# Specificity issue with conditional rendering of list items in React & SCSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to apply styles for every individual list item, after having applied styles for every list item with the more general "li" element identifier. The elements only have the li styles applied currently, even though the (I believe) more specific selector of className in React has styles defined below in SCSS stylesheet.

**SCSS for dropdown React Components, which contain li elements**

```
& .dropdownUl {
      margin: $boxMargin;
      padding: $stdPad;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      & li {
        padding: $stdPad;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        @include standard-1px-border;
        position: absolute;
        background: $linear-gradient-azn-nfx;

        &:hover {
          cursor: pointer;
          background: $netflix-red;
          color: $netflix-white;
        }
        &:active {
          background: darken($netflix-red, 10%);
        }

        & .dropdownLiTwo {
          top: 200px;
          background: black;
        }
        & .dropdownLiThree {
          top: 400px;
          background: black;
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

**Here is the component (dropdown-menu):**

```
import React from "react";

export default class DropdownUlOne extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showListItems: false };
    this.handleMouseEnter = this.handleMouseEnter.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseLeave = this.handleMouseLeave.bind(this);
  }

  handleMouseEnter(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      showListItems: true
    });
  }

  handleMouseLeave(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ showListItems: false });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.showListItems) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <ul className="dropdownUl" onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}>
            <h2 className="hoverOn">Home</h2>
            <li className="dropdownLiOne">Blog</li>
            <li className="dropdownLiTwo">UI & UX</li>
            <li className="dropdownLiThree">What you can expect</li>
          </ul>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ul className="dropdownUl" onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}>
          <h2>Home</h2>
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

**Which is rendered in this component to which the css of the scss is imported:**

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/header.css";
import DropdownUlOne from "./dropdownUlOne";
import DropdownUlTwo from "./dropdownUlTwo";
import DropdownUlThree from "./dropdownUlThree";

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header className="header">
        <h1 className="appTitle">Ronnlid Websites</h1>
        <div className="dropdownDiv">
          <DropdownUlOne />
          <DropdownUlTwo />
          <DropdownUlThree />
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question. However I think your problem here of the LI styles not applying is because of the `&` selector just before them so instead try:

```
& .dropdownUl {
  margin: $boxMargin;
  padding: $stdPad;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  li {
    padding: $stdPad;
    ....
```

The way the scss is structured now it's targeting an li with the class you have on the ul like this: `<li class="dropdownUl">`